# How can I specify visible columns on a GridControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have bound a collection from my database to a DevX `GridControl`.
By default, it is shows all columns.  How can I modify my Xaml code to strictly show the columns that I specify?

Here is the Xaml code:

```
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="lst1" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaImpianti}" ColumnsSource="{Binding c}" 
                     EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346"
                     FilterCriteria="{Binding FilterCriteria, ElementName=searchControl}" Height="479" >
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="CODICE" Binding="{Binding CODICE}" FieldName="CODICE"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="NOME" Binding="{Binding NOME}" FieldName="NOME"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"  ShowTotalSummary="True" AllowEditing="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

`ListaImpianti` is the query result from the ViewModel. It contains numerous fields and I would like to only show the fields `NOME` and `CODICE`.

Comment: I don't know if this the way to set the columns if you only require 2 to be displayed, have you tried creating the columns manually and then assign what you want to them, avoiding autogeneration?

Comment: I have edited the code. I have inserted the gridcontrol.colums, but the final results is the same... did you mean this with your comment?

Comment: you need to remove `AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew"` and it should work.

Comment: No worries, it was a quick solution so I don't think there is a need for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: remove AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, however, I was using a `GridControl` from within a `ControlTemplate` that was embedded within a `LookUpEdit` control.  I found it rather frustrating since no option within the `AutoGenerateColumns` had any effect.  After a bit of further digging, I found that the `LookUpEdit` control has a property called `AutoPopulateColumns` which overrides this value.  The property is a boolean and setting it to `False` will allow you to manually define your own columns.